# Invalid hook call. How to set a value with react axios get call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, state

I have this react component that has a simple form where, when you put a superhero name, it makes an axios get request to an API that responds successfully with json object with info of said hero. That info is stored in the state and then mapped through to create a grid. It used to work just fine as a class element so I started doing other parts of the app that have nothing to do with this part, but when i run the whole app again so check i get an hook call error in this component.

This is the seeker component, i did the class and the funcion version.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from 'formik';
import axios from "axios";
require("babel-core/register");
require("babel-polyfill");
import grid from "../components/grid";


/* 
const Seeker = () => {
   const fetchData = (data) => {axios.get(`https://www.superheroapi.com/api.php/1589015884770221/search/${name}`)
       .then((response) => {
           localStorage.setItem("addHeroAction", true);
           let results = response.data.results;
           localStorage.setItem("matchedHeros", results);
       }).catch((error) => {
           console.log(error)
       })
   }

   let matchedHeros = localStorage.getItem("matchedHeros") ? localStorage.getItem("matchedHeros") : [];
   
   const gridRender = (response) =>{
       if(response.length && response != undefined){
           console.log(response)
           return( 
           <div className="grid__background">
           <div className="grid">
               <div className="grid__box grid__top grid__top--container"></div>
               <div className="grid__box grid__top grid__top--container"><h2>Name</h2></div>
               <div className="grid__box grid__top grid__top--container"><h2>Intelligence</h2></div>
               <div className="grid__box grid__top grid__top--container"><h2>Strenght</h2></div>
               <div className="grid__box grid__top grid__top--container"><h2>Speed</h2></div>
               <div className="grid__box grid__top grid__top--container"><h2>Durability</h2></div>
               <div className="grid__box grid__top grid__top--container"><h2>Power</h2></div>
               <div className="grid__box grid__top grid__top--container"><h2>Combat</h2></div>
               <div className="grid__box grid__top grid__top--container"></div>
               {response.map(hero => grid(hero, hero.id))}
           </div>
           </div>)
       } else {
           return (<div></div>)
       }
   }

   return (
       <div>
           <h1>Find your next teammate!</h1>
               <Formik
               initialValues={{ name: ''}}
               validate={values => {
                   const errors = {};
                   if (!values.name) {
                       errors.name = 'Required';
                   } else if (
                       !/^[a-zA-Z]*$/.test(values.name)
                   ) {
                       errors.name = 'Invalid name';
                   }
                   return errors;
               }}
               onSubmit={(values) => {
                   console.log(fetchData(values.name));
               }}
               >
               {() => (
                   <Form>
                   <Field type="text" name="name" />
                   <ErrorMessage name="name" component="div" />
                   <button type="submit">
                       Submit
                   </button>
                   </Form>
               )}
               </Formik>
                   {gridRender(matchedHeros)}
       </div>
       )
   } */


   class Seeker extends React.Component{
   state = {
       matchedHeros : [],
       loadingData : true
   }
   constructor(){
       super();
       this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
   }

   
   fetchData = async (name) => {
       if(this.state.loadingData){
           await axios.get(`https://www.superheroapi.com/api.php/1589015884770221/search/${name}`)
           .then((response) => {
               localStorage.setItem("addHeroAction", true);
               this.setState({matchedHeros : response.data.results, loadingData : false});
           }).catch((error) => {
               console.log(error)
           })
       }
  
       
   }     

   
   render(){
       return (
           <div>
               <h1>Find your next teammate!</h1>
                   <Formik
                   initialValues={{ name: ''}}
                   validate={values => {
                       const errors = {};
                       if (!values.name) {
                           errors.name = 'Required';
                       } else if (
                           !/^[a-zA-Z]*$/.test(values.name)
                       ) {
                           errors.name = 'Invalid name';
                       }
                       return errors;
                   }}
                   onSubmit={(values) => {
                       this.fetchData(values.name);
                   }}
                   >
                   {() => (
                       <Form>
                       <Field type="text" name="name" />
                       <ErrorMessage name="name" component="div" />
                       <button type="submit">
                           Submit
                       </button>
                       </Form>
                   )}
                   </Formik>
                   {console.log(this.state.matchedHeros)}
                   {this.state.matchedHeros.length ?  
                       (
                       <div className="grid__background">
                           <div className="grid">
                               <div className="grid__box grid__top grid__top--container"></div>
                               <div className="grid__box grid__top grid__top--container"><h2>Name</h2></div>
                               <div className="grid__box grid__top grid__top--container"><h2>Intelligence</h2></div>
                               <div className="grid__box grid__top grid__top--container"><h2>Strenght</h2></div>
                               <div className="grid__box grid__top grid__top--container"><h2>Speed</h2></div>
                               <div className="grid__box grid__top grid__top--container"><h2>Durability</h2></div>
                               <div className="grid__box grid__top grid__top--container"><h2>Power</h2></div>
                               <div className="grid__box grid__top grid__top--container"><h2>Combat</h2></div>
                               <div className="grid__box grid__top grid__top--container"></div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                       )
                       :
                       <div></div>
                   }
                   {this.state.matchedHeros.map(hero => grid(hero, hero.id))}
           </div>
           )
   }
} 


export default Seeker;
```

It uses the formik library to verified the values and the it maps the info with a Grid component that works just fine on its own, so the problem is in this component. The axios call also sets a value in localStorage that i need to be set when the button is clicked.

The original was the class component but with it I have this error on the console.

"Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component."

Then i made the functional component version, which is commented in the code above, but with it i can't get the state updated with axios.

When i look into someone else's examples they look like mine but I still get the hook call error, i already checked that i have up-to-date versions of react so that's not the problem.
What am I doing wrong? or else, what suggestion can you guys give me to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get heroes when component is initially mounted:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

async function getHeros(name) {
    return axios.get(
        `https://www.superheroapi.com/api.php/1589015884770221/search/${name}`
    );
}

const Seeker = () => {
    const [heros, setHeros] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getHeros('someName').then((heros) => {
            console.log('heros: ', heros);
            setHeros(heros);
            localStorage.setItem("matchedHeros", heros);
        }, console.error);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {heros.map((hero, i) => (
                <span>{hero}</span>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! it does work but not for the purpose i was looking for. How can i make it in a way so that when i submit the name of the hero (which is written by the user in the input) the getHeros call gets the value and does the search with it? Because if i try to put the useEffect call inside other function and then call said function when i submit the form i get the same error from formik abput invalid hooks calls.

Comment: UseEffect goes at the root of the component, not inside arbitrary functions. It's main use is as lifecycle handles for when the component is initially mounted, or when it gets updated. Here, the [] at the end  of the useEffect makes it act similar to 'componentDidMount for class based components. To accomplish what you want you should google, "fetching data on submit react" for some code examples. Although, I think you'd benefit most from watching a tutorial or two on youtube for creating a simple react project.